# Jquery datatable dynamic filtering

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

The header content and the number of columns in my data table will differ.So i cannot declare thead or tfoot statically.
Is there any way to introduce the tfoot dynamically ?
Currenlty i am inserting header as below.

i want to achieve filtering on each column of the data table.Tried columnfilter but it requires tfoot to be declared statically(not dynamic)

```
var columns=[
        { "sTitle": "Customer ID","mData": "customerId", "sWidth": "15%" },
        { "sTitle": "ID","mData": "Id", "sWidth": "10%"  },
        { "sTitle": "Customer Name","mData": "primaryName", "sWidth": "15%"          },
        { "sTitle": "Email","mData": "primaryEmail", "sWidth": "20%"  },
        { "sTitle": "Contact Number","mData": "phoneNumber", "sWidth": "20%"  },
        { "sTitle": "Last Updateds","mData": "lastUpdated" , "sWidth": "20%"  }
    ];

var oTable = $('#table_panel2').dataTable( {
  "sDom": 'ipl<"dt_actions">tip"',
  "oLanguage": {
    "sLengthMenu": "_MENU_",
    "sInfo": "_START_-_END_ of _TOTAL_ ",
    "oPaginate": {
      "sNext": '',
      "sLast": '',
      "sFirst": '',
      "sPrevious": '' }
  },
  "bAutoWidth": false, 
  "sPaginationType": "full_numbers",
  "iDisplayLength": 15,
  "aLengthMenu": [[15, 30, 50, 100, -1], ["Show: 15 Results","Show: 30 Results","Show: 50 Results","Show: 100 Results", "Show All Results"]],
  "sAjaxSource" : 'simpleSearch.html?searchString='+p,
  "aoColumns": columns
});
```

Comment: would be easier to solve, if you attach a jsfiddle with question

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/J55xK/   need filter on each column with out declaring tfoot in html .Thanks in advance

Comment: check if this link helps you http://www.datatables.net/examples/api/multi_filter_select.html

Comment: Thanks Dave.thanks for the link.The tfoot has to be declared in this case also.I had to do                                               var html = '<th></th><th></th><th></th><th></th><th></th><th></th>';
  $('#table_panel2 tfoot tr').append(html);                                  since i am not sure about the number of columns.is there a work around for this?